# Rename "emails" tag to "email"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

"emails" is a terrible term; email by itself is already a mass noun.

Can we have "emails" renamed to "email"?

Comment: Done.  Why isnt there a "tag-rename", or "bad-tag" tag?

Comment: Because nobody has created one yet and you don't have the privs to do so.

Comment: What, this isn't a standard discussion topic on every meta-site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Private beta cleanup: tag synonyms and tag merges](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/423/private-beta-cleanup-tag-synonyms-and-tag-merges) - [this answer in particular](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/466/305).

Comment: Yes, the tag should be [tag:email]. Not only because it's a mass noun (but it can also be a countable noun), but because that's the name that SO, SU, SF, AU, U&L, Android and Apple use.

Comment: @Flyk It's better to discuss tags separately: one thread per tag or group of closely-related tag. Those mass tag questions are too broad, items tend to get lost there.

Comment: Done...........

Answer (score 5):

## Let's use [email]

Why? Well, emails is really the end result, but primarily because every other Stack Exchange site with an email tag uses [email] instead of [emails]. Let's keep it consistent.